# istio error: Details: java.io.IOException: Unknown apiVersionKind

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, istio

I receive this error message in jenkins when trying to deploy my application to kubernetes. Is there something I am missing?

> istio-gateway.yml ERROR: ERROR: java.io.IOException: ERROR: YAML file
>   istio-gateway.yml is invalid, please check it. Details:
>   java.io.IOException: Unknown apiVersionKind:
>   networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/Gateway known kinds are...

I am using Spring Boot with Java

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a [Istio Geteway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) using that yaml. You probably don't have istio installed in your Kubernetes cluster. If it's not installed then you need to [install](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/) it.